# How can I fix the 'ModuleNotFoundError' in my python docker container when running the main.py file?

Tags: python, docker, import

I am running a docker container from dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as the base image
FROM python:3.10.5

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /code/

RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pipenv install --system --dev

# Install Google Chrome dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
   #a lot of impiort
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Google Chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt --fix-broken install -y

# Download and install the latest stable ChromeDriver
RUN CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=$(curl --silent https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) && \
    wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    rm chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/

COPY . /code/

# run the main_daily_task.py file
CMD  ["python", "app/main_daily_task.py"]
```

I get the following error in docker container:

2023-05-25 16:27:46 Traceback (most recent call last):

2023-05-25 16:27:46   File "/code/app/main_daily_task.py", line 13, in <module>

2023-05-25 16:27:46     from app.database import SessionLocal

2023-05-25 16:27:46 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

However when I change the import to

```
from database import SessionLocal
```

it works.

I cannot change the import paths because some of the files are used in other containers, so I think the next best step is to change the working directory, but in the Dockerfile it is already correct.

How do i fix this issue, what am I doing wrong and why is my working directory code/app/ not code/ how i specified in the dockerfile?

Edit: maybe I need to specify the base_dir during runtime? But I think this is very ugly and not how it is sopposed to be.
Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

```
CMD  ["python", "/code/app/main_daily_task.py"]
```

Specify absolute path and make sure the python script has executable permission.

The app is not the python module. Here python considering the app not as directory but module in SessionLocale. It is better you try:

```
import database from SessionLocale
```

Comment: That didnt solve the problem, just caused an error - No such file in directory scraper        | python: can't open file '/code/code/app/main_daily_task.py'